# _co.JSON is undefined - Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to stringify an object using `JSON`, but when I load my page, I get this error:

> TypeError: _co.JSON is undefined

The stacktrace is huge and I don't think it would be of use to include.

This is the code that throws the error:

```
<div *ngFor="let asset of getAssets()">
      {{ JSON.stringify(asset) }}
</div>
```

The items in the array returned from my code-behind are all correct objects.

This is the output of `ng --version`:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to manipulate an array inside a `Promise.then`code-block. Refactoring to use `await` fixed my problem.

So instead of:

```
getAssets() {
  assetSet = new Set();
  for (let asset of this.assets) {
    assetSet.add(JSON.parse(asset);
  }
  return Array.from(assetSet);
} 

onSearchInputChange() {
  somePromiseFunction().then(response => this.assets = response);
}
```

I used:

```
getAssets() {
  assetSet = new Set();
  for (let asset of this.assets) {
    assetSet.add(JSON.parse(asset);
  }
  return Array.from(assetSet);
} 

async onSearchInputChange() {
  this.assets = await somePromiseFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON isn't known in template but you can try json pipe :

```
{{ asset | json }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The context in your component template interpolation is the "this" of the component. not window Object.

So if you want to do this you have to "declare" JSON in your component class

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    private JSON = window.JSON; 
    ...
}
```